# What is $\frac{\partial }{{\partial A}}tr({A^T}BA)$

Tags: calculus, matrices

What is $\frac{\partial }{{\partial A}}tr({A^T}BA)$?

My thoughts: $\frac{\partial }{{\partial A}}tr(AB{A^T}) = A(B + {B^T})$,
        hence $\frac{\partial }{{\partial {A^T}}}tr({A^T}B{A^{}}) = {A^T}(B + {B^T})$,
        hence $\frac{\partial }{{\partial A}}tr({A^T}BA) = {({A^T}(B + {B^T}))^T} = (B + {B^T})A$.

Am I right?

Supplement:
Both A and B are matrix. B is constant, and $\frac{\partial }{{\partial A}}$ is derivation over A, defined as $(\partial /\partial {a_{ij}})$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities

Comment: How is $\partial/\partial A$ defined?

Comment: I take from the link that it is defined as matrix $(\partial/\partial a_{ij})$.

Comment: Both A and B are matrix. B is constant, and $\frac{\partial }{{\partial A}}$ is derivation over A.

Comment: @Batman: Thank you so much! I got the answer from wikipedia! But there is one thing I'm not quite clear of. Does "Numerator layout" represents $(\partial /\partial {a_{ji}})$ and "Denominator layout" represents $(\partial /\partial {a_{ij}})$? Thank you so much!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ user148926, your result is correct. Let $f(A)=tr(A^TBA)$. Then the derivative is $Df_A:H\rightarrow tr(H^TBA+A^TBH)=tr((A^TB^T+A^TB)H)$. And the gradient is $\nabla(f)_A=BA+B^TA$.